# Wordpress: Admin-Ajax.php sending out emails not sure why

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been having this issue lately with my admin-ajax.php file and I'm not sure why. On my Wordpress site, I've been using the page-builder plugin Elementor. I save my progress quite frequently, and checking the developer console in Google Chrome, I can see that with every save the plugin makes a call to my admin-ajax.php file. Apparently, every time I do this it's causing an email to be sent out (to where and to whom I'm not sure) and my hosting is contacting me about receiving a large (spam) number of emails from my file and are asking me to disable my admin-ajax.php file. The problem is I can't because I won't be able to save my progress.

Is there anyway I can take out any of the code below so there won't be an email sent out every time I save or anything I can do? my admin-ajax.php code is posted below as is. I look forward to any help. Thanks

```
<?php
/**
 * WordPress Ajax Process Execution
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
 */
/**
 * Executing Ajax process.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
define( 'DOING_AJAX', true );
if ( ! defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
}
/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/wp-load.php' );
/** Allow for cross-domain requests (from the front end). */
send_origin_headers();
// Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    die( '0' );
/** Load WordPress Administration APIs */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
/** Load Ajax Handlers for WordPress Core */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php' );
@header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
@header( 'X-Robots-Tag: noindex' );
send_nosniff_header();
nocache_headers();
/** This action is documented in wp-admin/admin.php */
do_action( 'admin_init' );
$core_actions_get = array(
    'fetch-list', 'ajax-tag-search', 'wp-compression-test', 'imgedit-preview', 'oembed-cache',
    'autocomplete-user', 'dashboard-widgets', 'logged-in',
);
$core_actions_post = array(
    'oembed-cache', 'image-editor', 'delete-comment', 'delete-tag', 'delete-link',
    'delete-meta', 'delete-post', 'trash-post', 'untrash-post', 'delete-page', 'dim-comment',
    'add-link-category', 'add-tag', 'get-tagcloud', 'get-comments', 'replyto-comment',
    'edit-comment', 'add-menu-item', 'add-meta', 'add-user', 'closed-postboxes',
    'hidden-columns', 'update-welcome-panel', 'menu-get-metabox', 'wp-link-ajax',
    'menu-locations-save', 'menu-quick-search', 'meta-box-order', 'get-permalink',
    'sample-permalink', 'inline-save', 'inline-save-tax', 'find_posts', 'widgets-order',
    'save-widget', 'delete-inactive-widgets', 'set-post-thumbnail', 'date_format', 'time_format',
    'wp-remove-post-lock', 'dismiss-wp-pointer', 'upload-attachment', 'get-attachment',
    'query-attachments', 'save-attachment', 'save-attachment-compat', 'send-link-to-editor',
    'send-attachment-to-editor', 'save-attachment-order', 'heartbeat', 'get-revision-diffs',
    'save-user-color-scheme', 'update-widget', 'query-themes', 'parse-embed', 'set-attachment-thumbnail',
    'parse-media-shortcode', 'destroy-sessions', 'install-plugin', 'update-plugin', 'press-this-save-post',
    'press-this-add-category', 'crop-image', 'generate-password', 'save-wporg-username', 'delete-plugin',
    'search-plugins', 'search-install-plugins', 'activate-plugin', 'update-theme', 'delete-theme',
    'install-theme', 'get-post-thumbnail-html', 'get-community-events',
);
// Deprecated
$core_actions_post[] = 'wp-fullscreen-save-post';
// Register core Ajax calls.
if ( ! empty( $_GET['action'] ) && in_array( $_GET['action'], $core_actions_get ) )
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_GET['action'], 'wp_ajax_' . str_replace( '-', '_', $_GET['action'] ), 1 );
if ( ! empty( $_POST['action'] ) && in_array( $_POST['action'], $core_actions_post ) )
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_POST['action'], 'wp_ajax_' . str_replace( '-', '_', $_POST['action'] ), 1 );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_heartbeat', 'wp_ajax_nopriv_heartbeat', 1 );
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    /**
     * Fires authenticated Ajax actions for logged-in users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the Ajax action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
} else {
    /**
     * Fires non-authenticated Ajax actions for logged-out users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the Ajax action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
// Default status
die( '0' );
```

Comment: It sounds like your website has been compromised. You will need to locate and remove the malicious source code, and find and patch the vulnerability that was exploited to prevent the issue continuing.

Comment: There are several .php files being "required" into action in your script, check each of those for any mail functions. If your hunt doesn't turn anything up then I'd say that your server has been compromised.

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting server and I've looked through the required .php files and I'm not finding any mail functions. Is there anything specific I should look for

Comment: If your code has been compromised, the malicious code is most likely base64 encoded or something to prevent you finding it easily. If you're on shared hosting, they may have a support team who can investigate and resolve the issue for you for a fee.

Comment: I had already contacted them and they said I'd have to consult with a developer because they just do hosting and the issue is beyond their realm of knowledge

Answer (score 0):

admin-ajax.php is the file that handles all ajax calls in a Wordpress wbesite unless another ajax handler is specified. The code that sends the emails you wrote about will not be found within admin-ajax.php. The function that sends those emails only use admin-ajax.php in order to send the email asynchronously.  Search your theme and plugins for function that begin with

- `wp_ajax_`
- `wp_ajax_nopriv_`

And then check if any of these functions are set to send emails. After finding the PHP function that sends the email you might want to search for the JavaScript file that is send the Ajax request to this PHP function. That should help you pinpoint the culprit behind this email business.